# How to remove artifact from cloudbees release repository?

Tags: repository, cloudbees

I performed few excessive releases to my cloudbees releases repo, so now I need to clean it up. But there is no visible way to remove artifact from repo.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a webdav client such as [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/). More [info](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Mounting+DAV+Repositories)